# Does Scala Optimize Method Definition with a Constant Return Value?

Tags: scala, optimization

Does Scala optimize a method definition with a constant return value to a val?

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  override def getMap(): Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "one")
}

trait MyTrait {
  def getMap() : Map[Int, String]
}
```

Optimized to?

```
class MyClass extends MyTrait {
  val getMap: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "one")
}
```

This way giving the programmer the choice of using a dynamic definition when necessary.

Comment: Interesting question... Any idea @dk14 ?

Comment: Overriding `def getMap` with `val getMap` is already valid scala. So you do have a choice. `val` essentially creates a field and a getter method with same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. `val` and `def` have different contracts, with consequences in the language. Path dependent types cannot be based on `def`, and while a `def` may be overridden by a `val`, the reverse is false.

Specifically, the value returned by a `val` is guaranteed to be the same every time, once initialized, whereas `def` can return different values every time it is called.

One could think of optimization given a case where a literal is called, but that is not the case in your code. `Map(1 -> "one")` is a method call, and could well return different values every time (just like `def`).

Oh, minor detail, in case you are interested: both `val` and `def` are implemented with method calls, though the former reads from a field, whereas the latter doesn't.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for that detail, will have to look up their implementation now :D

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not. In fact, `scalac` cannot do this. This could only  be done by the VM, which has complete information about the program at runtime. Here's why.

First, some class `SubClass` could extend `MyClass` and override `getMap` with another method. If `scalac` did implement this optimization, the `SubClass` would have an empty bogus field from its superclass, and an increased footprint.

Second, `scalac` does not know how `Map` is implemented. If the `Map` factory has side-effects, this optimization would prevent them from executing each time `getMap` is called. This changes the semantics of the program. There are some [early attempts to overcome this](http://webmail.dev411.com/p/gg/scala-internals/14a93nf1qf/attacking-binary-compatibility-at-the-root-with-typed-trees), and retain more information for the compiler to be able to analyze this, but you should be aware that such an optimization could still break reflection features relied upon by dependency injection and mocking frameworks.

Finally, it's not clear when this is really an optimization. If the return expression were really cheap (e.g. a number), it would increase the memory footprint of the class to cache a value that can be computed with almost no effort.

Btw, what you describe is not a static function definition, but a *method definition with a constant return value*.

Comment: I am pretty sure the compiler could be programmed to figure it out for the first case.  The second case is very much valid.  Thanks for the clarification, will update question title.

Comment: You're right - it absolutely could. Problem is - is this what you'd like? What if you extend `MyClass` very often, and always override `getMap` with an implementation? Then every subclass would have an extra empty field inherited from `MyClass` that only consumes memory.